# What magic is used to access state via variable reference in functional React components?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I cannot grasp what kind of magic is used when after `useState` we can reference to state in `return` block and it receives updated value on re-render...

For example in pure JS original array cannot influence destructed value ("v" will be with original value 1):

```
const arr = [1];
let [v] = arr;
arr[0] = 2;
console.log(v);
```

But with React magic "cnt" is changing if state is updated...

```
function App() {
  let [cnt, setCnt] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <div>Counter: {cnt}</div>
        <button onClick={() => {setCnt(cnt+1)}}>Inc</button>
```

Does React transpile the code of `cnt` to some `MAGIC_MAP["cnt"]` in the `return` block?

With class components we explicitly keep state in `this` according to the rules of JS execution engine.

**UPDATE** React docs has some vague hints:

https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

> We declare a state variable called count, and set it to 0. React will remember its current value between re-renders, and provide the most recent one to our function. If we want to update the current count, we can call setCount.

https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-does-react-associate-hook-calls-with-components

> There is an internal list of “memory cells” associated with each component. They’re just JavaScript objects where we can put some data. When you call a Hook like useState(), it reads the current cell (or initializes it during the first render), and then moves the pointer to the next one. This is how multiple useState() calls each get independent local state.

Comment: React source code: https://github.com/facebook/react :)

Comment: If you are looking for a short summary https://www.newline.co/@CarlMungazi/a-journey-through-the-usestate-hook--a4983397 this helps?

Comment: It's not clear to me what "magic" you're referring to.  If state is updated then the whole component re-renders.  So `cnt` is *re-declared* in the new render and assigned whatever value `useState` returns.  Are you asking how the internals of `useState` are implemented?  The internals of the state setter function it returns?  Something else?  If you're looking to learn about React's internal implementation, its source code is the place to start.  But it's not really clear to me what you're looking to learn.

Comment: @David I don't get what is `cnt` in `return` block and how the value is initialized. What is pure JS equivalent if the code written with `React.createElement()` ? Does it possible or we have to resort to class style components?

Comment: @gavenkoa: *"what is cnt in return block and how the value is initialized"* - It's a variable, declared in the first line of the function, initialized to the value that `useState` returns.  As for how to achieve React-like functionality without using React, for that you're going to have to start learning React's source code.  That's **far** too broad to be meaningfully answered here.  But there's definitely no "magic" involved. A variable is declared at the start of a function, it's assigned a value, and that value is used throughout the function. Like any other variable in any other function.

Comment: @David I think I get it. My initials thought was that `App` is evaluating once and the value in `return` is used by React. If React evaluates `App()` each time then the value of `cnt` will be updated from `useState()`.

Comment: Are you trying to implement your own version of react with the jsx and hook feature?

Answer (score 1):

My misunderstanding came from the assumption that functional component represented by a return value instead of by a function.

So the function is called each time the component re-render. I assumed that function is called once and return value is re-used: so wondered what way value of state is updated. In reality `useState` is called every re-render so the value is assigned as just JS variable, no magic.